How to spot a "centre-bias operator"?
I recently asked this question after noticing abnormally good results from a popular "nature-based meta-heuristic algorithm".  I established by "origin shifting" that the method was not really any good, and stopped using it.  During the discussion there was a reference to this paper, which lists a large number of bad algorithms containing a "centre-bias" operator, but gives no indication about how one might directly detect one (by inspection, rather than by measurement).
A few days ago I noticed this paper, which claims to do just that for one popular algorithm.  Unfortunately the article is paywalled, so I cannot read it (which is annoying!). Here is what I can see:

Internet searching for such an operator is of no avail, so I am asking here; is there any publicly available guidance to detect such an operator in an optimization algorithm by inspection, or can anyone here give any?
